# How to attach mouse events to hidden SVG elements?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an `<rect>` tag inside the `<svg>` and instead of setting `visibility : hidden;` css property to rectangle, I just apply `stroke : none; fill : none;` to it. But the `onclick` event now is not getting called.
Is there any way I can get the `onclick` on invisible rectangle in svg? I am sharing my code. JavaScript part is inline within HTML.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Demo</title>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <svg id = "oSvg" height = "900" width = "1200"></svg>
  <script>
   var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
   var rect = document.createElementNS(svgns, "rect");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 100);
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "y", 200);
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "200");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "300");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', 'stroke:none; fill : none;')
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'onclick', 'console.log("Rect click");');
   document.getElementById("oSvg").appendChild(rect);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Also tried the same code with jQuery, still couldn't find the solution

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <svg id = "oSvg" height = "900" width = "1200"></svg>
  <script>
   var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
   var rect = document.createElementNS(svgns, "rect");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 100);
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "y", 200);
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "200");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "300");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', 'stroke:none; fill : none;')
   document.getElementById("oSvg").appendChild(rect);
   $(rect).on('click', function() {
    console.log("hello");
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to bind click dynamically using `on` in JQuery. I hope that will work.

Comment: @Abinthaha tried using jquery on function, but not working. Thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: Could you share the jQuery code you tried so far?

Comment: @Abinthaha added the jQuery code in the question

Answer (score 1):

The default [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events) value is `visiblePainted`, in which if you remove both the stroke and the fill of your svg shape, there is nothing left for your pointer event to end on.

So you have to set it explicitly to `visibleFill`, `visible`, `fill` or `all` if you want to keep using `fill="none"`.

```js
document.querySelector('rect').onclick = function(){
  console.log('clicked on the rect');
}
```

```css
svg {border: 1px solid;}
```

```html
<svg>
<rect pointer-events="all" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="150"/>
</svg>
```

<s>Alternatively, you could set the fill to transparent.</s> (I've been told it's not a good idea actually, even though it would work...)

Also note that

- `setAttributeNS(null,...`  is just `setAttribute(...`
- adding event listeners as attribute is highly discouraged as it means you'll be only able to run the callbacks from global scope.

Comment: @kaiido setting fill="transparent" is also discouraged as it's less efficient than using pointer-events

Comment: @RobertLongson good to know, is the performance issue that big? And if so why? I would have thought that for pointer parts, it would just be like an opaque `fill` and for renderer well... still less work than semi-alpha compositing.

Comment: The browsers will paint the area, with fill="none" they know they can take a shortcut and not render anything. Firefox has optimisations for opacity="0" and fill="none" but not for fill="transparent"

Comment: @RobertLongson ok, so I guess it's really implementation dependent. I can very well imagine other UAs have this optimisation (I guess it's there in most HTML renderers and sounds like a *could be incorporated* in some SVG renderers). Will take this into consideration anyway from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `fill: none`, I used `opacity: 0`. And it is working. Please let me know if it is okay for you.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <svg id = "oSvg" height = "900" width = "1200"></svg>
  <script>
   var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
   var rect = document.createElementNS(svgns, "rect");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 100);
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "y", 200);
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "200");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "300");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)");
   rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', 'stroke:none; opacity: 0;')
   document.getElementById("oSvg").appendChild(rect);
   $(rect).on('click', function() {
    console.log("hello");
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```